# How to describe interval datatype in mysql?

Tags: mysql, time

I'm now working on a mysql database. I have a need to have 2 columns in tables:
The first one has to store info in format "N years M months".
The other one: "H hours MM minutes".
can you give me an idea about how to represent it in table? I know, that mysql doesn't provide any time interval datatype. I will appreciate your opinions very much.

Comment: there is no "interval" type. you'll have to hack together something. e.g. convert years/months to a number of days, and the time values into a number of seconds, then store them as plain integers

Comment: I would use the [ISO-8601 spec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations), for which a lot of languages have libraries ready to go.

Comment: @Wrikken it's a simple student homework and I do not need any professional realization.

Comment: Wait wtf? You ask what a proper format is, I hand you a widely used formal specification, and that isn't to your liking? Moreover: _because you are a student_ this isn't relevant? Especially with that reason sir, you just blew my mind. I'd like to know more about which country has mindset that you should _NOT_ learn students how the world works, and that they _specifically_ should stay well clear of _standards_.

Comment: @user3014909 Please edit your post and include an example: What you already have and what would you like to get. Also, if possible, include whatever you've tried to solve your issue

Comment: The answer depends very much on what you want to do with those fields.

Answer (score 0):

If your database choice is not fixed, it's worth noting that PostgreSQL has a native time/date interval type that might readily represent your desired intervals.

But let's assume that MySQL is what you've got to work with. Then you're going to need a homegrown way to represent your intervals, because [MySQL doesn't have any native ones](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html).

1. A simple approach would be to represent intervals in terms of a least common denominator, such as "seconds." H hours and MM minutes = `H * 3600 + MM * 60`. Converting back to H and MM would be done through division, modulo, or `divmod` operations.
2. Another approach would be to use concatenated strings, such as N years M months = `"N,M"` and H hours MM minutes = `"H:MM"`.

   Either way, your logic (SQL and/or application language) will have to interpret these composed types. String concatenation is not especially efficient, but it's easily decomposed in most programming languages. E.g. in Python:

   ```
   years, months =  [int(part) for part in yearmonth.split(',')]
   ```

   It's a little less convenient in SQL, but combinations of `left`, `right`, and `locate` will do the trick (possibly with the rare addition of `cast`).

A bigger problem is that while your hours and minutes intervals are well-defined, your years and months intervals are less so. Neither years nor months have a fixed number of days (hours, seconds, etc.). There are leap years, and months have varied lengths. You can either assume a fixed value as an estimate (e.g. `365.25 days/year` taking into account leap years, or the even more accurate `365.2425 days/year` taking into account the special handling of 100- and 400-year marks). This is often done when estimating, such as `4.33 weeks/month`. Just keep in mind, those are estimates. If you keep the intervals as composed strings, you can use an external library such as Perl's [Date::Manip](http://search.cpan.org/~sbeck/Date-Manip-6.47/lib/Date/Manip.pod) that has considerable savvy about dealing with date intervals. Which brings us to a final option:

3. Choose an external interval interpretation library, and commit to using its encoding of intervals. For example, [Date::Manip::Delta](http://search.cpan.org/~sbeck/Date-Manip-6.47/lib/Date/Manip/Delta.pod) compacts 7 fields (years, months, weeks, days, hours, minutes, and seconds) into a colon-separated string such as `1:2:3:4:5:6:7`. If you're going to depend on an external library, might as well choose its native format. Other languages and libraries have their own favored formats. Just be careful in choosing one that has a semantic understanding of the passing of time that maps well to your application needs. Not all will. For example, Python does have a native `datetime.timedelta` type, but days are the largest unit in its understanding. That might not map well to your need for years and months to have full expression. As [Wrikken suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136544/how-to-describe-interval-datatype-in-mysql/27137138#comment42771370_27136544), if you have a libraries that support [a standard representation like ISO8601 durations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations), all the better. I, however, have not found such libraries to be as common, well-supported, or richly functional as alternatives such as `Date::Manip`.